# nlog when filter not taking effect?

Tags: nlog

I have this `rule` in my nlog.config. (There are other rules but this is the only one which ends up sending email, and therefore the only one to be debugged):

```xml
<rules>
    <logger name="*cxml*" minlevel="Info" writeto="customer">
        <filters>
            <when condition="not equals('${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_HOST},'interestinghost.com')" action="ignore" />
        </filters>
    </logger>
</rules>
```

This should ensure that **Info** level messages, from the loggers with **cxml** in the logger name, should be written to the **customer** target; but when the `HTTP_HOST` server variable does not equal **interestinghost.com**, the Info message should be ignored. Thus only messages regarding **interestinghost.com** should end up being emailed.

The **customer** target sends an email, and has this definition. Notice that the layout includes the `HTTP_HOST` variable:

```xml
<target name="customer" xsi:type="Mail" 
        smtpServer="..." smtpPort="587" smtpAuthentication="Basic"
        smtpUserName="..." smtpPassword="..." enableSsl="true" 
        from="..." to="..." cc="..." 
        subject="log from ${logger} ${longdate}"
        layout="===================${aspnet-request:serverVariable=REQUEST_METHOD} ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=SERVER_PORT} ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_HOST}${aspnet-request:serverVariable=URL} ${aspnet-request:serverVariable=QUERY_STRING} ${newline}${level} | ${longdate} | ${logger} ${stacktrace:topframes=5}| ${message} | ${exception:format=Message,ShortType,StackTrace}"
        encoding="iso-8859-2" />
```

Nevertheless, my actual customer reports he is getting messages he shouldn't -- in particular, messages that are directed to another `HTTP_HOST`:

```
===================POST 80 boring.noninteresting.host/cxml/setup
Warn | 2016-06-15 13:33:38.4817 | application.page.logger => Page.ProcessRequest => Page.ProcessRequestMain => Control.LoadRecursive => cxmlSetup.Page_Load => LoggerImpl.Write| Sending cXML PunchOutSetupResponse message: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<!DOCTYPE cXML SYSTEM "http://xml.cxml.org/schemas/cXML/1.2.014/cXML.dtd">
<cXML xml:lang="en-US" payloadID....
```

How could this possibly be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a missing single quote on your function, between the right brace and the comma.

```
                                                     ↓↓
not equals('${aspnet-request:serverVariable=HTTP_HOST},'interestinghost.com')
```

Comment: Wow, I had missed the quotes on the first param completely. Sometimes it really is the simplest things.